# chart.js draw custom grid lines

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I'm looking for option to draw custom grid instead of using the default one. The result I want to have is this one. 
[image]

At first I tried to extend the chart plugin by accessing its functions and changing contents of grid lines but couldn't do anything I want. Later I found this [plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation)  and thought that was my solution but it were not neither. Also I found this `afterFit` event with callback on offsets and tried to manipulate it but also nothing. Btw I'm using [chart.js for vue.js](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs) and of course with vue.js. Those grid lines must be constant and not move or change it place. I'm starting to think there are no option to solve the problem with chart.js

Comment: I think you probably want to look at the grid line section in styling in the docs - http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration

Comment: already did, nothing that could help me.

Answer (score 1):

In `vue-chartjs`, the second argument of `renderChart()` is the [options config](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs#another-example-with-options) for the chart, which can contain `scales.xAxes` and `scales.yAxes` properties to set the color of the axes (i.e., the grid):

```js
this.renderChart( /* data */ , {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      display: true,
      gridLines: {
        display: true,
        color: '#eee'
      },
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      gridLines: {
        display: true,
        color: '#eee'
      },
    }]
  }
})
```

```js
Vue.component('line-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Data One',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
        }
      ],
    }, {
      responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            color: '#444'
          },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            color: '#444'
          },
        }]
      }
    })
  }
  
})

new Vue({
  el: '.app',
})
```

```css
.app {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#2e3f61, #131b29);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs@3.0.1-rc2/dist/vue-chartjs.js"></script>
<div class="app">
  <line-chart></line-chart>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats not what I asked at all. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, I was unable to create custom gridlines using chart.js. The C3.js package contains far more customisation options for gridlines and gives the option of providing custom/user-defined grid lines, described [here](https://c3js.org/samples/grid_x_lines.html).

C3.js available [here](https://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html).

Comment: See my answer. Chart.js should be able to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ticks dictionary which you define inside scales > xAxes/yAxes.

The options autoskip: false and source: 'data' should work.